# C++ vector as member of Objective C class doesn't retain value

Tags: objective-c++

So I've got an Objective C class that will implement the NSTableViewDataSource protocol to display a list of audio output devices. I'm calling a C++ class that returns device information as a std::vector of C structs of the form

```
typedef struct DeviceInfo {
    AudioDeviceID devID;
    char name[128];
    int nInputChannels;
    int nOutputChannels;
} DeviceInfo;
```

The Objective C class is

```
@interface PreferencesViewController : NSObject <NSTableViewDataSource> {

    AudioOutputController *audioOutputController_;
    vector<DeviceInfo> audioOutputDevices_;
}

- (void)setAudioOutputController:(AudioOutputController *)controller;
- (void)updateDeviceList;
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

The main app controller sets the PreferencesViewController's AudioOutputController member (the C++ class), then calls updateDeviceList(), which tells the AudioOutputController to query the available audio devices and return a vector of DeviceInfo structs

```
- (void)updateDeviceList {
    /* Update the list of currently connected devices and return device information */
    audioOutputController_->setAvailableDevices();

    audioOutputDevices_.clear();
    audioOutputDevices_ = audioOutputController_->getAvailableDevices();

    for (int i = 0; i < audioOutputDevices_.size(); i++) {
        printf("Device %d: %s\n", i, audioOutputDevices_[i].name);
        printf("\t%d Output Channels\n", audioOutputDevices_[i].nOutputChannels);
    }
 }
```

This all works completely fine and prints the available audio devices, but the vector of structs doesn't seem to retain its value outside updateDeviceList(), so I see an empty vector when I try to access it in the NSTableViewDataSource protocol methods. If I try to just print the size of the vector in an IBAction method, for example

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    printf("audioOutputDevices_.size() = %lu\n", audioOutputDevices_.size());
}
```

it says the vector is empty. I'm new to combining C++ and Objective C, so any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: something else peculiar. If I call PreferencesViewController's updateDeviceList() method from the AppDelegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching(), as follows:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    audioOutputController_ = new AudioOutputController();
    preferences_ = [[PreferencesViewController alloc] init];
    [preferences_ setAudioOutputController:audioOutputController_];
    [preferences_ updateDeviceList:self];

}
@end
```

then I get the problem stated above, with the C++ vector not retaining its value. If I instead make updateDeviceList() an IBAction callback for an interface button, then when I call it it retains its value and the device information gets added to the table.

Comment: Everything looks fine. You must be doing something you're not realizing.

Comment: are you compiling with ARC enabled?

Comment: ARC is enabled. I found a way to get the vector to retain its value, but the solution isn't optimal. See the edit in the original post.

Answer (score -1):

I believe (from a similar experience of mine) that during application startup the C++ constructor of `vector<DeviceInfo> audioOutputDevices_` is somehow called again, which clears it.